# Why extension is not dependent on friction here?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, elasticity

> A ideal rod has mass $m$ and length $l$) is pulled by a constant force $F$ on a rough horizontal floor (of coefficient of friction $\mu$). Let its Young's Modulus of elasticity of the rod to be $Y$

I assumed an element of the rod of length $dx$ at a distance $x$ from the beginning, so the forces acting on that point is,

- $ \frac{L-x}{L}F=F_1$ in the direction of $F$
- $ \frac{L-x-dx}{L}F$ and $dm\mu  g= \frac{\mu mg dx}{l} $ in the direction opposite to $F$ and let their sum to be $F_2$

As the element is very small the tension on it is $ \frac{F_1+F_2}{2}=F_{dx}$

So, let's assume extension on this element to be $dl$

$$dl= \frac{F_{dx} dx}{AY} $$
$$\Delta l=\int_0^l \frac{ \frac{F(2l-2x-dx)+\mu mg dx}{2l} dx}{AY} 
 $$ I neglected $dx$ terms which gave$$\Delta l=\int_0^l \frac{ \frac{F(l-x)}{l} dx}{AY}$$

And finally,
$$\Delta l = \frac{Fl}{2AY} $$

Why is now extension not dependent on friction? Or If I am doing wrong please correct me.